# jqgrid automated columns width

Tags: jqgrid

I have a table where I show some columns depending on users choice stored in database.
What I want is:

- If all columns width is shorter than table width, expand columns to use the entire table width.
- If all columns width is longer than table width, make columns narrower so no horizontal scrollbar appears.
- If I manually change a column width within the table (using the vertical line next to the column header), I need the other columns to autoresize so the full width is 100% (not longer nor narrower) of table width.

I've been using the parameters *autowidth*, *shrinkToFit* and *forceFit*, but when full width is ok, then if I resize a column manually a horizontal scrollbar appears. I cannot find the correct combination of those parameters so the table behaves like that.

Any idea on how to put those values to get my aim?

Thank you very much-

Comment: I think I've found the solution. It works fine although when a lot of columns are shown, their width make them almost impossible to read properly, but at least, the full width is always 100%.

Comment: The combination of those three parameters is: 
forcefit: true, shrinktofit:true, autowidth: true